# How to run C language code on JetBrains CLion

Tags: c, clion

I get the following error :

> Error:Neither MinGW nor Cygwin is selected

Do you have idea for resolve this issue?

Comment: Select MinGW or Cygwin?

Comment: how select MinGW ? , i install MinGW on my windows OS machine

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To elaborate on the answer provided by "uta" you need either MinGW or Cygwin in order to compile your code. MinGW can be obtained from here: [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)

Or Cygwin from here:
[Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html)

For simplicity I will describe MinGW. Install MinGW then navigate like so in CLion:

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Toolchains

And select the directory you have MinGW installed. I believe by default on Windows it's *C:\MinGW*. Once you've done this CLion will scan the directory and detect it.

If you already have them installed then you need only select the folders they're installed in in CLion.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please, start from menu:
File | Settings... | Build, Execution,... | Toolchains | Environment:

Comment: How about MSVC? Isn't supported?

Comment: Sorry, but currently CLion is not working with MS compiler. Mostly because MS compiler is not providing preprocessor info extraction.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206556469-What-compiler-debugger-can-I-use-within-CLion-

Comment: CLion now supports MSVC with its last version: https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2017/03/clion-2017-1-released/#msvc. It is currently marked as unstable and debugger isn't supported, but it seems to work fine.